# Bincode::deserialize_from with BufferedReader

Tags: rust, file-io, binaryfiles, binary-data

I am using a toy example, but the actual one is one scale of very large binary file that was written in the same manner.

Im trying to read from a very large binary file that i've written myself with bincode as well

The whole idea is to easily use Bincode in order to create big files and iterate on them later

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde;
extern crate bincode;

// use std::fs::File;
use bincode::serialize_into;
use std::io::BufWriter;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct MyStruct {
    counter: Vec<u32>,
    offset: usize,
}

impl MyStruct {
    // omitted for conciseness
    pub fn new(counter: Vec<u32>, offset: usize) -> Self {
        Self { counter, offset }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(100);
    vec.push(500);
    vec.push(100);
    vec.push(500);
    vec.push(100);
    vec.push(500);
    let m = MyStruct::new(vec, 0);

    // fill entries in the counter vector

    let mut f = BufWriter::new(File::create("foo2.bar").unwrap());
    serialize_into(&mut f, &m).unwrap();
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(100);
    vec.push(600);
    vec.push(100);
    vec.push(500);
    vec.push(100);
    vec.push(600);
    vec.push(500);
    vec.push(101241241);
    vec.push(600);
    let m2 = MyStruct::new(vec, 35);
    serialize_into(&mut f, &m2).unwrap();
    drop(f);
    // let mut buffer;
    // buffer = BufReader::open_raw_file("foo2.bar").unwrap();
    let input = File::open("foo2.bar").unwrap();
    // let buffered = BufReader::new(input);
    let mut vecs: Vec<MyStruct> = Vec::new();
    loop {
        match bincode::deserialize_from(&input) {
            Ok(file) => vecs.push(file),
            Err(error) => break,
        };
    }

}
```

However, due to read on raw file, it is very slow
How can I use BuffReader to speed up my code inside bincode::deserialize_from?

```
let input = File::open("foo2.bar").unwrap();
let buffered = BufReader::new(input);
```

Comment: You showed how you can do that.

Comment: The problem that BuffReader does noot work with continious loop, the trait bound `&std::io::BufReader<File>: std::io::Read` is not satisfied

Comment: you can with `&mut buffered`

Answer (score 2):

Usage of `BufReader`:

```
let input = File::open("foo2.bar").unwrap();
let mut buffered = BufReader::new(input);
let mut vecs: Vec<MyStruct> = Vec::new();
loop {
    match bincode::deserialize_from(&mut buffered) {
        Ok(file) => vecs.push(file),
        Err(error) => break,
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! speeded up everything by a huge margin